# AAD B2C Migration - ROPC Sign In Custom Policy with Rest-API Integ with Legacy IDP - Is that supported?

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-security

Im trying to do **seamless-account-migration** listed here, since our Passwords are **hashed** and our users are in DB,  https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/user-migration

We are using a mobile  device and got users to  migrate  from an Database as part of Migration,
I followed

1) **ROPC Custom Policy**  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/ropc-custom?tabs=app-reg-ga

2) **Defined custom attributes** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-custom-attributes

3) **Setup a Rest-API on Legacy IDP to return migrationStatus** 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-rest-api-intro

However, I think the **ROPC with REST-API** is not supported ? because the

ROPC has **Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect"**
vs

SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email has **Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"**

and  ran into problem of

> Invalid technical profile with id "ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentials-OAUTH2" only the protocol handler **""Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider""** can have a **ValidationTechnicalProfile**

I stumbled upon these and noticed, the **seamless migration** with **Rest API** during **Sign-In** does not apply for ROPC (mobile devices) ? Is that true ?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/self-asserted-technical-profile

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/openid-connect-technical-profile

Can someone tell me how do we do migration during **SignIn with Rest-API interaction for ROPC grant_type** ?

**User Journey**

```
<UserJourney Id="ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentials">
  <PreserveOriginalAssertion>false</PreserveOriginalAssertion>
  <OrchestrationSteps>      
    <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
  </OrchestrationSteps>
</UserJourney>
```

and here is the **SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email** Technical Profile  via **Self Asserted** Protocol

as I was not able to Upload ROPC Technical Profile with **ValidationTechnicalProfile** via **OpenIdConnect** Protocol as it said  the  error stated before,

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_isMigrated" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <!--Add user migration validation technical profiles before login-NonInteractive -->

            <!-- Populate extension_requireMigration into the claims pipeline -->
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="Get-requiresMigration-status-signin" ContinueOnError="false" />

            <!-- If extension_requireMigration is true, call the legacy IdP via the REST API -->
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="REST-ValidateProfile" ContinueOnError="false">
              <Preconditions>
                <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                  <Value>extension_isMigrated</Value>
                  <Value>True</Value>
                  <Action>SkipThisValidationTechnicalProfile</Action>
                </Precondition>
              </Preconditions>
            </ValidationTechnicalProfile>

            <!-- If the API returned 'tokensuccess', write the new password and unmark the account for migration -->
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-WritePasswordAndFlipMigratedFlag" ContinueOnError="false">
              <Preconditions>
                <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                  <Value>requiresMigration</Value>
                  <Value>False</Value>
                  <Action>SkipThisValidationTechnicalProfile</Action>
                </Precondition>
              </Preconditions>
            </ValidationTechnicalProfile>

            <!-- Initiate a normal logon against Azure AD B2C -->
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="login-NonInteractive" />
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

The ROPC Technical Profile, **ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentials-OAUTH2** I  tried to upload is below which failed with said error

```
    <TechnicalProfile Id="ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentials-OAUTH2">
      <DisplayName>Local Account SignIn</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">We can't seem to find your account</Item>
        <Item Key="UserMessageIfInvalidPassword">Your password is incorrect</Item>
        <Item Key="UserMessageIfOldPasswordUsed">Looks like you used an old password</Item>
        <Item Key="DiscoverMetadataByTokenIssuer">true</Item>
        <Item Key="ValidTokenIssuerPrefixes">https://sts.windows.net/</Item>
        <Item Key="METADATA">https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>
        <Item Key="authorization_endpoint">https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/token</Item>
        <Item Key="response_types">id_token</Item>
        <Item Key="response_mode">query</Item>
        <Item Key="scope">email openid</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="logonIdentifier" PartnerClaimType="username" Required="true" DefaultValue="{OIDC:Username}" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" Required="true" DefaultValue="{OIDC:Password}" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="grant_type" DefaultValue="password" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="scope" DefaultValue="openid" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="nca" PartnerClaimType="nca" DefaultValue="1" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="client_id" DefaultValue="XXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="resource_id" PartnerClaimType="resource" DefaultValue="XXXXXXXXXXX" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="oid" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" PartnerClaimType="upn" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_isMigrated" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaimsTransformations>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromObjectID" />
      </OutputClaimsTransformations>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
      <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <!--Add user migration validation technical profiles before login-NonInteractive -->

        <!-- Populate extension_requireMigration into the claims pipeline -->
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="Get-requiresMigration-status-signin" ContinueOnError="false" />

        <!-- If extension_requireMigration is true, call the legacy IdP via the REST API -->
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="REST-ValidateProfile" ContinueOnError="false">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>extension_isMigrated</Value>
              <Value>True</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisValidationTechnicalProfile</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
        </ValidationTechnicalProfile>

        <!-- If the API returned 'tokensuccess', write the new password and unmark the account for migration -->
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-WritePasswordAndFlipMigratedFlag" ContinueOnError="false">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>requiresMigration</Value>
              <Value>False</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisValidationTechnicalProfile</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
        </ValidationTechnicalProfile>

        <!-- Initiate a normal logon against Azure AD B2C -->
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="login-NonInteractive" />
      </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

Comment: Can you provide snippets of the technical profiles. ROPC should allow you now to call a REST API before the ROPC technical profile from the user journey. This was an enhancement to enable seamless account migration to work with ROPC flows.

Comment: @JasSuri I updated the code  fragments for  SelfAsserted as  I was  not able  to upload the xml  for ROPC  with  Validation Technical  Profile, let  me know  if  you need  that  as  well,

Comment: @JasSuri I uploaded both xmls fragments using OpenIdConnect and SelfAsserted , let me know if there is anything I need  to change to  get ,  ROPC SignIn->RestAPIValidate->AADWrite->token
Thanks  in  advance

Comment: @SudhakarBetha were you able to fix this issue? I have the same requirement for a project, tried everything but still getting erros when calling the endpoint

Answer (score 0):

Since its an ROPC policy, it cannot contain any selfasserted flows. What you need to do is create a journey like this:

Orchestration steps:

**Step 1.** Read user account using Email in B2C, output extension_requiresMigration

**Step 2.** If extension_requiresMigration = True -> Call REST API to send credentials to it. Return an error if the password is bad.

**Step 3.** If REST API said credentials are good -> Write user password to B2C account

**Step 4.** Run ROPC Technical profile (login-noninteractive)

**Step 5.** Read any other information from account in AAD B2C

**Step 6.** Issue a token